# Finding complex eigenvectors of $n \times n$ matrix, $n\geq 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

An example:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 0 \\
        2 & -3 & 4 \\
        4 & -8 & 7 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Has eigenvalues $3$, $1+2i$, $1-2i$. How would you find the eigenvectors for this matrix without annoying row-reduction algebra with complex numbers?

For example, if I choose $\lambda = 1+2i$, I will have a matrix as such:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -2i & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & -4-2i & 4 \\ 4 & -8 & 6-2i\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, if this were a $2 \times 2$ matrix, I would know that there has to be kernel with dimension $1$, so I could simply set one of the two rows to $0, 0$. But in a $3 \times 3$ matrix, setting any row to $0, 0, 0$ might result in my destroying a linearly independent row (although the odds are $1/3$). Is there an easy trick to find eigenvectors in such a situation without complex algebra?

Comment: I don't think there's a general way out but to solve the linear system. Perhaps in this or that *particular case* one can use some tricks, but in general I see no option.

Comment: No, there is no such way in general.

Comment: Here one can easily note that (1,1,1) is an eigenvector of 3. There is no general way to find the depedent row. There are speical cases, for example block-matrices.

Comment: @Mike There is a general algorithm, which is to find *the first row which is lin. dependent* on the preceeding ones. In the given example, this is obviously the last row.

Comment: @Timbuc Well of course there is an algorithm, just apply row actions until you find it; This is not the point.

Comment: No @Mike, is *much* simpler in this, and similar, cases: The first row is clearly lin. indep. as it isn't zero. The second row *clearly* isn't a scalar multiple of the first one, and thus it **must be** that the third row is a linear combination of the first two since we know a prior that the system is linear dependent. I think this is precisely the point in these cases.

Comment: @Timbuc You are right of course,This is precisely the solution for 3X3 matrcies, but this is good only for this case. I thought we were talking about the general case. The 4X4 case (and so on) is harder.

Comment: @Mike What I said in my past comment is good for any case, but indeed: it gets tougher and tougher.